# --go_out: protoc-gen-go: The system cannot find the file specified Windows 10

Tags: go, grpc

I am trying to use this command `protoc greet\greetpb\greet.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:`. I got that message

> "--go_out: protoc-gen-go: The system cannot find the file specified."

My protoc version is libprotoc 3.6.1
My go version go version go1.11.2 windows/386
Also into my package list is this github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/grpc

I am new using golang and I trying to learn grpc.
Could someone helps me with that problem? I am using windows 10.

Comment: Did you install proto-gen-go? If not, try running `go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go`

Answer (score 2):

I could solve that problem editing the environment variable PATH. I add %GOPATH%/bin and the command works.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is a flag for this if you are in a situation in which you can't update your PATH effectively (such as when using a plugin in VS Code that ignores updates to the editor's PATH).

If you run `protoc --help` you will find the entry below somewhere near the bottom of the list of options.

```bash
  --plugin=EXECUTABLE         Specifies a plugin executable to use.
                              Normally, protoc searches the PATH for
                              plugins, but you may specify additional
                              executables not in the path using this flag.
                              Additionally, EXECUTABLE may be of the form
                              NAME=PATH, in which case the given plugin name
                              is mapped to the given executable even if
                              the executable's own name differs.
```

This will allow you to run `protoc --plugin=path/to/protoc-gen-go` without having to update a potentially obscured or uneditable PATH environment variable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you have protobuf installed

```
brew install protobuf
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

this should install protoc-gen-go into your $GOPATH/bin

set your PATH environment variable to the above folder

```
PATH = :$GOPATH/bin:
```